# Why "might" is used in the following situation but not "might have"?

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

I found the sentense "he hesitated before ringing her, fearful of what she might say".

I wonder why "... might say" is used but not "... might have said"?

Answer (score 1):

In "might have said", "have said" is a perfect form. The perfect represents completed actions.

"Might have said" would imply that she might already have said it at the time of his hesitation, even though he hadn't rung her yet.

If, instead, he is fearful of what she might say on the phone once he rings her, her action clearly hasn't taken place yet at the time of his hesitation, so can't go into the perfect.